# Restricted cubic splines for time-to-event data

Tags: regression, rms

I'm kind of new in fitting rcs for cont. variables as a clinican, so I have a few questions:

```
d <- datadist(df)
options(datadist = "d")

model1 <- cph(Surv(time, status) ~ rcs(lfi, 3), data = df, x = TRUE, y = TRUE, surv = TRUE)
ggplot(Predict(model1))
```

1. Is this code correct to visualize the association of lfi on survival in univariable Cox?
2. Is Log relative Hazard on the y-axis appropriate?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answers to both your questions are "Yes", but perhaps need some explanation.

Let's use the `lung` data from the survival library for demonstration purposes, and fit a cox proportional hazard model wherein the effect of age is modelled as a restricted cubic spline.  The model is much like yours

```
library(rms)
library(survival)

dd <- datadist(lung)
options(datadist='dd')

fit <- cph(Surv(time, status)~rcs(age, 3), data=lung, x=T, y=T)

ggplot(Predict(fit))
```

[image]

The plot shown below is the log relative hazard, so yes the label is correct. Recall that the Cox model models the hazard as follows

$$ \lambda(t, X) = \lambda_0(t) \exp(X\beta) $$

That is to say, the hazard function is modelled non-parametrically, and the coefficients simply multiplicatively increase the hazard.  Here $X$ is a matrix consisting of the spline basis functions.  The relative hazard is $\exp(X\beta)$ since it is ratio between $\lambda(t, X)$ and $\lambda_0(t)$.  Consequently, the log relative hazard is $X\beta$ -- i.e. the linear predictor in the model.

It may be more sensible to actually plot the Relative hazard, since that gives us a better idea of the factor by which the hazard increases

```
ggplot(Predict(fit, fun = exp))
```

[image]

What we've done is basically take the exponential of the curve above.  We see that for subjects aged ~ 65 the hazard is 1.0 -- meaning the hazard for subjects aged ~65 is approximately $\lambda_0(t)$.  For those older than 65, the hazard is *larger* because the relative hazard is larger than 1.  For those younger than 65, the hazard is *smaller* since the relative hazard is smaller than 1.

This plot only shows what the *effect of age* on the hazard is.  It might be more sensible to instead plot the survival curve conditioned on age.  That can be accomplished with

```
# Or you can specify different ages as you like
rms::survplot(fit, age = c(45, 65, 85))
```

As you can tell, the survival plot accords with our understanding of how the relative hazard changes across ages.  Patients older than 65 have an increased hazard, hence lower survival curve.  The converse is the case for those aged younger than 45.

[image]

Comment: @sjg You're better off posting another question.