# Reporting of Cox model w/ restr. cubic splines

Tags: regression, cox-model, splines

I'm new in fitting multivariable Cox models w/ restricted cubic splines.

This is my code:

```
d <- datadist(df)
options(datadist = "d")

mod_full <- cph(Surv(time, status) ~ rcs(age, 3) + sex + weight, data = df, x = TRUE, y = TRUE, surv = TRUE)

mod_full
summary(mod_full)
anova(mod_full)
```

However, I'm not quite sure how to interpret & report the model. In a model w/o RCS, I would just report HR + 95% CI + p. Would be very thankful for some insights.

Answer (score 3):

Let's again start with the `lung` data from the `{survival}` package and fit a similar model.  We will expand age in a restricted cubic spline and also model the effect of calories consumed at meals.  The model is

```r
library(rms)
library(survival)

dd <- datadist(lung)
options('datadist'=dd)

fit <- cph(Surv(time, status) ~ rcs(age, 3) + meal.cal, data=lung, x=T, y=T)
```

Let $X$ be the design matrix containing spline basis functions and let $W$ be the calories consumed at meals.  The model for the hazard is

$$ \lambda(t; X, W) = \lambda_0(t) \exp(X\beta + W\gamma) $$

Here, $\lambda_0(t)$ is the baseline hazard, $\beta$ are the regression coefficients for the spline and $\gamma$ is the regression coefficient for calories.

Since we're using a spline basis with 3 knots for age, we should have 2 basis functions in $X$ meaning we have 3 total regression coefficients: 2 for age, 1 for calories.  We can verify this by print fit to the console

```r
> fit
Frequencies of Missing Values Due to Each Variable
Surv(time, status)                age           meal.cal 
                 0                  0                 47 

Cox Proportional Hazards Model

cph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ rcs(age, 3) + meal.cal, data = lung, 
    x = T, y = T)


                       Model Tests    Discrimination    
                                             Indexes    
Obs       181    LR chi2      4.00    R2       0.022    
Events    134    d.f.            3    R2(3,181)0.006    
Center 0.5728    Pr(> chi2) 0.2611    R2(3,134)0.007    
                 Score chi2   4.16    Dxy      0.108    
                 Pr(> chi2) 0.2449                      

         Coef   S.E.   Wald Z Pr(>|Z|)
age      0.0077 0.0218  0.35  0.7236  
age'     0.0149 0.0257  0.58  0.5624  
meal.cal 0.0000 0.0002 -0.07  0.9406
```

The coefficients presented here are the log hazard ratios and their standard errors.  This is typically what you put in a table 2; it will allow other people to fit a similar model on their data.  One could evaluate a hypothesis test for calories consumed from meals from this (in this case, its clear there is a negligible effect of calories on survival, if there is an effect at all).  However, the spline is more complicated.  The spline is the *set* of coefficients all together, so interpreting a hypothesis test for any one coefficient is meaningless.

Instead, we can use `anova` to perform a joint test for the spline coefficients.

```r
> anova(fit)
                Wald Statistics          Response: Surv(time, status) 

 Factor     Chi-Square d.f. P     
 age        3.80       2    0.1498
  Nonlinear 0.34       1    0.5624
 meal.cal   0.01       1    0.9406
 TOTAL      4.12       3    0.2490
```

Its been a while since I've used `rms` so I hope someone can correct the following if I am wrong.  The statistics reported here are <s>likelihood ratio chi-square statistics</s> Wald statistics estimated from the estimated covariance matrix.  You can see that the chi square statistic and p value for calories is very similar to the wald statistic and p value printed out in the last step.  There is a good reason for this I will not get into.

Age has 2 chi-square statistics.  The first tests for *any* effect of age (i.e. $H_0: \beta = 0$ vs $H_A: \beta \neq 0$).  The second tests of there is a non-linear effect of age by testing *just* the coefficients which would produce a non-linear relative hazard.

What do you report?  Report both.  You should report confidence intervals and point estimates for all coefficients in the model, but also report *relevant* tests of hypothesis from the `anova` call.

It would also be sensible to plot these effects while holding other variables constant, something we covered [in this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/643860/restricted-cubic-splines-for-time-to-event-data/643868#643868).

Comment: +1, I'd also suggest plotting the non-linear effect + CI's. This is usually done selecting a fixed set (or sets) of variables besides the non-linear one and then plotting the predictions + CI's across a grid of the non-linear variables.

Comment: @CliffAB This is an extension of another question OP made in which we covered plotting the (log) relative hazard

Comment: Got it. Sorry for being picky, but it might be nice to add a one liner + link to that question as I would consider that to be a key part of reporting such a model as the question is written without having to know the backstory.

Comment: @CliffAB Ok, Done.

Comment: Thank you very much – this is really helpful. One minor point: with anova I got a p vaue of 0.07 for age, and for age nonlinear p = 0.026. Could it be that age per se has no significant effect but in the non-linear range it does?

Comment: @sjg P values in isolation aren't super useful.  All I can tell you is that you've failed to reject the null hypothesis for any effect of age, but there might be some non-linearity in whatever the estimated effect is.  I would encourage you to plot the relative hazard for age (as we did in the previous question) and interpret from there.

Comment: As I understand its [help page](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/rms/html/anova.rms.html), the default in `anova.rms()` is a Wald statistic (or an F statistic in `ols` models) with corresponding chi-square tests based on the variance-covariance matrix. Likelihood-ratio chi-square tests can be requested for several model types. (+1)

Comment: @EdM oh that’s dumb of me, it says Wald statistic right there in the output.

Comment: I use `rms` a lot more frequently than you do, I think. For example,  just 3 hours ago.